# Customizing Locust input params

Tags: python, performance, locust

So I have locust running in a distributed set up on k8s. Currently I am kicking off load tests via the UI. In my current set up, the master and worker processes are running already and are waiting for me to kick off the load test via the UI. I am looking to add some input customization for my locust set up. I just want to accept some more params like endpoint weights and such. This then should attach to the already existing locust process and kick off a load test with the proper configuration. I know locust supports extending UI to see more of the load test output, but I couldn't find anything that would extend/customize the input form.

[image]

[EDIT]

I am trying to use [custom arguments](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/extending-locust.html#custom-arguments) and it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code

```
class CusLoadTest(HttpUser):

      @events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
      def _(parser):
         parser.add_argument("--user-count", type=str, env_var="USER_COUNT", default="1000", help="1000")

      def __init__(self, parent):
          super(CusLoadTest, self).__init__(parent)

      def __check_environment(self):
         self.user_count = int(self.environment.parsed_options.user_count)
         logger.info("Using {}".format(self.user_count))

      def on_start(self):
          self.__check_environment()
```

The logger always prints 1000 users and ignores anything I pass into the web UI. Not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locust has supported adding custom parameters on the command line for a while, but the ability to set those arguments in the Web UI (and forward them to workers in distributed runs) was added just recently (in 2.2.0)

See https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/extending-locust.html#custom-arguments for a full documentation.

If you have some custom settings you *don't* want to show in the UI, you'll need the latest prerelease build (as that feature is not yet in a release). 2.2.2.dev30 is the most recent one.

Comment: Oh wow! How did I miss that? Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: looks like custom arguments aren't working as expected. I've added more information in the original question.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to me that you just changed your question into an entirely new one. I think you should change it back and maybe file a github issue for the problem you are having now. It should work. The only thing I see that is special about your code is that you run  @events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener *inside* a user (instead of at top level)

Comment: I think the problem was that I was using USER_COUNT as my params name and that somehow doesn't work. Changing the name seems to work. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I think the name user_count happens to be used in the web gui for the total number of users (—users on command line) in some places, maybe thats what was causing the issue.